# Authenticating in MS Azure AD with returned SAML 2.0 artifact from another IdP

Tags: authentication, azure

Our web app has enduser sso authentication with one governmental Identity provider. This IdP is SAML 2.0 based. The web app is calling a web service registered in MS Azure AD and will require authentication with some kind of token. All the examples I have seen so far about authenticating in Azure AD is based on JWT Bearer tokens.

#### Is there a way I can use the successful enduser (SAML 2.0) returned token/artifact in the web app to authenticate against the Azure AD tenant so I can call the Azure AD web service?

Comment: Hey there. I removed the header from your text. It is implied that the first paragraph is context while the second one is a question, no need to state it. Make sure to only write what is directly relevant for your question. It is not rude to not overstate that you're looking for helpful actions from the community :) I hope someone will have knowledge of your problem! You may want to improve your question further by adding links to the resources you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you cannot achieve what you want!

Azure AD **is** Identity Provider itself. At the moment Azure AD cannot **federate** to another Identity Provider (except only internally to Live ID).

When you create an application in Azure AD (register the app), you just create a trust between Azure AD and your application. And you make your application to **only trust Azure AD**. In this picture there is no place for your other SAML-P identity provider.

The only way you can achieve what you ask for, is to **establish trust** between the **SAML provider** and **Azure AD**. And this, at the moment is not supported by Azure AD.

If your web application is only calling the Web API via server side code (not from client side), you can use the Client Credential OAuth flow. To achieve that you have to register your Web Application with Azure AD and explicitly grant access for it to your Web API application registered in Azure AD. Check [this documentation for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx).